# implementing doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have trouble implementing a doubly linked list, especially in a function that swaps adjacent elements.

Here is my original code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data; 
    node *prev;
    node *next;
};
node *head = NULL;

node* getNewNode (int i){
    node *newNode = new node; //allocate a dynamic memory in the heap
    newNode->data = i;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void InsertAtHead(int i){
    node *newNode = getNewNode(i);
    if (head == NULL){   //addressing inserting the first node in the list.
        head =  newNode;
        return;
    }
    
    newNode->next = head;
    head->prev = newNode;
    head = newNode;    
}

void swapAdjacent() {
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL ) {
        node *temp1 = temp;
        node *temp2 = temp->next;
        temp1->next = temp2->next;
        temp2->prev = temp1->prev;
        if (temp1->prev != NULL) {
            temp1->prev->next = temp2;
        }
        temp1->prev = temp2;
        temp2->next = temp1;
       
        if (temp == head) {
            head = temp2;
        }
        temp = temp->next->next;
    }
}

void display (){
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        cout  <<temp->data << '\t';
        temp = temp->next;    
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main (){
    InsertAtHead(8); 
    InsertAtHead(4);
    InsertAtHead(12);
    InsertAtHead(3);
    InsertAtHead(-8);
    InsertAtHead(7);
    cout << "The original list is: " << endl;
    display();
    swapAdjacent();
    cout << "The list after swapping the adjacent elements is: " << endl;
    display();
       
    return 0;
}
```

The original list is:

```
7       -8      3       12      4       8
```

The output I got after calling `swapAdjacent()` is:

```
-8      7       3       4       12      8
```

While I am looking for:

```
-8     7       12      3        8       4
```

I tried visualizing this with pen and paper, did several attempts to look it up, and I even used ChatGPT, but to no avail. I always don't get the output I am looking for.

My question is that I want the swapAdjacent() function to produce the desired output and not the output it is currently producing.

Comment: "*I tried visualizing this with pen and paper*" - good for you. Most people don't bother doing that at first. However, if you had actually done that properly (or, if you had stepped through the code with a debugger), you should have found your mistake pretty easily.

Comment: yes. I wrote in my original submission the desired output and the the actual output I am getting. I want the swapAdjacent() function to produce the desired output. is this not a valid programming question?

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  Also, I highly recommend drawing the nodes and their links as you step through your program.

Comment: Please don't write the answer into the question or as a comment. You can fix the question, wait until it's reopened and write an answer.

Comment: put display inside that swap adjecent loop, that way you can see the progress. The point it that you need to operate on pairs according to your expected output. But you are not doing that , you work your way down the list one by one, it should be in twos

Comment: I hope that you are aware that your implementation is badly designed in many different ways (owning pointers, function naming, and the fact that [`<list>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) exists). I hope you do not intend on actually *using* this implementation for anything, and that "am I doing this right?" ("NO!") is out of scope for the question.

Comment: (1) In order to swap two nodes, you need to change up to six `next` and `prev` pointers. You are only changing up to 5. Think about `temp2->next->prev`  (2) Before the swap, `temp` looks at the left node. After the swap, `temp` looks at the right node, so `temp->next->next` has an extra `->next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your feedback. I figure out what was wrong with my code which basically I forget to update the pointer of the next node (prev variable).Also, I was going forward one node extra. Here is my updated code. I welcome all of your feedback.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
int data; 
node *prev;
node *next;
};

node *head = NULL; 

node* getNewNode (int i){
node *newNode = new node;  //allocate a dynamic memory in the heap
newNode->data = i;
newNode->prev = NULL;
newNode->next = NULL;
return newNode;
}

void InsertAtHead(int i){
node *newNode = getNewNode(i);
if (head == NULL){    //addressing inserting the first node in the list.
    head =  newNode;
    return;
}
newNode->next = head;
head->prev = newNode;
head = newNode;    
}

void swapAdjacent() {
node *temp = head;
while (temp != NULL && temp->next!=NULL ) {
    node *temp1 = temp;
    node *temp2 = temp->next;
     if(temp2->next != NULL){
        temp2->next->prev = temp1;
    }
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->prev = temp1->prev;
    if (temp1->prev != NULL) {
        temp1->prev->next = temp2;
    }
    temp1->prev = temp2;
    temp2->next = temp1;
   
    if (temp == head) {
        head = temp2;
    }
   
    temp = temp->next;
}
}

void display (){
node *temp = head;
while (temp != NULL){
    cout  <<temp->data << '\t';
    temp = temp->next;    
}
cout << '\n';
}

int main (){
InsertAtHead(8); 
InsertAtHead(4);
InsertAtHead(12);
InsertAtHead(3);
InsertAtHead(-8);
InsertAtHead(7);
cout << "The original list is: " << endl;
display();
swapAdjacent();
cout << "The list after swapping the adjacent elements is: " << endl;
display();
   
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are these issues:

- `temp = temp->next->next;` is making one step forward too many (as you can also notice in the output you get): as `temp` now points to a node that was swapped with its original successor, it is now pointing to the node that is the direct predecessor of the next pair. So you just need to move up one step: `temp = temp->next;`
- Your code makes at the most 5 assignments to either a `prev` or `next` pointer. This should be alarming you. When swapping 2 neighboring nodes, there are up to 4 nodes impacted: the two nodes themselves, the successor after the pair, and the predecessor before the pair. When these 4 nodes have been put in their right order, there are 3 connections that are impacted in both directions, so there could be up to **6** pointers that need to be updated. You're missing one update. It is the update of the `next` pointer that belongs to the predecessor.
- Your code is accessing `temp2->next` without ensuring that `temp2` is not null. This could happen when your list has an odd number of nodes. I would suggest changing your `while` condition so that it assert there is a **pair** of nodes.

Here is the corrected code:

```
void swapAdjacent() {
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp && temp->next) { // Require that we have a pair
        node *temp1 = temp;
        node *temp2 = temp->next;
        temp1->next = temp2->next;
        if (temp1->next) { // Must change also in opposite direction
            temp1->next->prev = temp1;
        }
        temp2->prev = temp1->prev;
        if (temp1->prev) {
            temp1->prev->next = temp2;
        }
        temp1->prev = temp2;
        temp2->next = temp1;
       
        if (temp == head) {
            head = temp2;
        }
        temp = temp->next; // Only a single step is needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there a problem with my answer that you removed the acceptance mark 10 months later?